# Accept WCF request in WebAPI

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I need to enable my webAPI REST service to accept a request in the format of:

`www.someURL.com/OldService.svc`

I am working on an existing application that used to use WCF. These methods do not have to return anything but a 200 response. We need the REST service to handle this call so we can retire the old WCF service, but systems will fail if we don't support this WCF request.

Has anybody done this before?

**edit:**

Is it possible to do this with just adding a new route?

Comment: I fail to see the problem. If you create the .svc with underlying class, it should work fine. Have you tried it?

Comment: the new rest service doesn't have a .svc

Comment: Can't you leave the old service running as-is and then have a separate url for your webapi stuff?

Comment: We dont want to pay for to keep the old service running

Comment: WCF only works with SOAP and Web API with REST, not SOAP. While you *can* make a REST service understand SOAP with a *lot* of code, you would end up with a solution worse than a WCF service. If you want to expose both a REST and a SOAP endpoint, extract the common code to a separate class and call it from both services. You don't "pay" anything to do this.

Comment: I have fiddler traces of the request/responses. I was going to create a route to accept these requests and simply return the same exact response to the request every time. However for simplicity, I just added a WCF service to my web API project to not clutter the code with whatever that would involve

Comment: Also, I don't care about the data actually sent with the SOAP request because I am returning the same response for every single request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a WCF service (.svc) to a Web API project by simply adding a New Item and selecting Web, it will then show up in the list as WCF Service.

Comment: I ended up going with this solution because it was the easiest. It only added a small section to my web.config and I only have a couple files to delete if we choose to do so in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the Route attribute(using System.Web.Http) for the old service? I've used this for route names like [Route("SomeRoute")] but I'm not 100% sure if the .svc extension will interfere with anything.

```
[Route("OldService.svc")]
    [HttpPost]        
    public HttpResponseMessage NewData(Data SomeData)
    {}
```

Comment: It's not a routing problem - what would Web API do with the SOAP envelope? At best you would end up with the entire XML message which you would have to parse to extract the actual data

Comment: I tried doing something like this but I could not get the route to work. @PanagiotisKanavos, I don't care about the envelope in the request body, I would ignore it anyway and just return a generic response.